# Is encrypting web.config pointless?

Tags: .net, asp.net, encryption, web-config

I was reading a blog today (http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/is-encrypting-your-web-config-a-waste-of-time/) about both how to encrypt your appsettings/connectionstrings etc. using the aspnet_regiis tool.

He has a follow up post with some feedback from others saying this is a waste of time.

My question is, what do you think? Are you totally hosed as soon as anyone gets physical access to your web.config files anyway? Or is this a worthwhile precaution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it is pointless.  If someone does gain access to your web server, yes you are in a lot of trouble.  Does that mean that you need to allow them to gain that same access to your database/middle-tier/application server as well?

Comment: If you connect to your database using a trusted connection then reading your web.config still won't help them get the database password.

Answer (score 3):

You are only as strong as your weakest part. Any measures you can take to improve security are a good thing, although this is not something i do.

I share the view that if people have got access to your web.configs, youve probably got worse issues to worry about.

I always make sure any db usernames/passwords stored within have datareader/datawriter ONLY on the site's database.

One thing you can do is have them encrypted as part of your deploy, using a build tool such as MSBuild, NAnt, Rake etc. this way its not so much of an effort and therefore more likely to be accepted by your team